# ArgumentError on CSV output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm getting the following error when trying to generate a CSV:

ArgumentError in ProductsController#schedulecsv

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

My Products controller is set up as follows:

```
 def schedulecsv
 products = Product.find(:all)
 filename ="schedule_#{Date.today.strftime('%d%b%y')}"
  csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << Product.csv_header
      products.each do |p|
        csv << p.to_csv
      end
  end
  send_data csv_data,
  :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
  :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{filename}.csv"
 end
```

Does anyone have any pointers here? Driving me bonkers!

Thanks!

Comment: can u post the full error message..

Comment: ArgumentError in ProductsController#schedulecsv

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Rails.root: /Users/ryanberry/dashboard
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:52:in `generate'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:52:in `schedulecsv'

Request

Parameters:

None

Show session dump

Show env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Comment: you need to pass filename in generate call,see answer below

Comment: CSV.generate does not exist in Ruby 1.8, which version of ruby are you using..

Answer (score 1):

From source of csv.rb place in /usr/lib/ruby/(version of your ruby gem)/csv.rb (on my machine)

Here is source code of `CSV` class's `generate` method

```
def CSV.generate(path, fs = nil, rs = nil, &block)
  open_writer(path, 'w', fs, rs, &block)
end
```

`generate` method require `filename` as parameter.it will make file with given name,but  You are calling `CSV.generate` filename was missed

so you have to passed name of file in generate call!

```
filename ="schedule_#{Date.today.strftime('%d%b%y')}"
CSV.generate filename do |csv|
  csv << Product.csv_header
  products.each do |p|
    csv << p.to_csv
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, still having some trouble. Where should the CSV.rb file be? I don't have the section of code you've posted below....

Comment: csv.rb is actually source of CSV class you are using for generating csv,i post source code of `generate` function of `CSV` class.yes wording are bit confusing updating my answer